# Treeview navigation

Tags: navigation

I have a need to display SharePoint content as a treeview. What are the available options? I'd rather use a solution that doesn't require server side implementation (hosted SharePoint), and works on both SP 2007 and SP 2010.

My content could be either default SharePoint stuff (sites/lists/folders/items), or specific content (e.g. topics/documents/Web pages).

What I am looking for is similar to the treview available in the left navigation area of SharePoint sites, but I need one that I can customize with my own hierarchy and icon set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would tell you to go with a mix of two great products on the market, both open source and free.

To get your data, i would tell you to get the SPServices jQuery extensions. Check it [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).  This extension let you use the SharePoint Web Service infrastructure from client side and is mainly compatible with SharePoint 2007 and 2010.

The other product, to display your result, an other jQuery extension, jQuery treeview.  Check it [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/).  With that product, you will be able to get the incoming result from the SharePoint Web Services, and without too many manipulations, display it in a treeview form.

Good luck!